# Basic jQuery: Can't get an appropriate result using 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

My goal is to make alert the user that whichever shape they click on will correspond with an appropriate message.

My problem at the moment is that I am using an if statement that if the user clicks on something with the background color of blue, it will alert them saying they clicked on a circle. Otherwise they have clicked on a square.

The results are that clicking on the blue circle will alert that we have clicked on a square.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-color") == "blue") {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a square!");
  }
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Try debugging your code (using the browser's developer tools, not alert()), and see what the actual value of `$(this).css("background-color")` is

Comment: `$(this).css("background-color")` returns "rga(0,0,255)". Don't use CSS values to determine the shape, use `class` or `data-*` attributes instead. See https://jsfiddle.net/4k4ff31e/

Comment: @haim770 I know its a terribly inefficient way of determining the shape, I was trying it out as an experiment. I used borderRadius as a test with == "50%" and it works so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: @haim770 Ah I see. CSS returns them as RGB values so using "blue" would not work...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.css() returns an RGB value for background colors.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a square!");
  }
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get response back as rgb values, not the actual English word.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a square!");
  }
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it even more extensible, you could use the class name as the thing you alert:

```
$("div").click(function() {
  alert('This is a ' + $(this).prop('class'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is assigned by the class not directly, the `.css("background-color")` will returns the `rgb()` value, It's better to check the `class` or the `id` attributes in your condition instead, check the sample below :

```
$("div").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("square") ) {
    alert("This is a square!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("square") ) {
    alert("This is a square!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  }
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).css("background-color"));
  if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {
    alert("This is a circle!");
  } else {
    alert("This is a square!");
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` is not the same as `.` in CSS, nor their corresponding HTML properties.  This is not a distinction that is here to make problems for you, it is one introduced intentionally with a purposeful design that you must reflect in your applications to benefit from.

`#` or the `id` attribute is *only* for user-defined identifiers that are unique within the document.  The behavior of the document element's namespace dictionary allows one to address sub-document fragments with URIs.  If you want generalities in presentation or behavior, `id` is not the attribute one should use in the document's markup.  The level at which this anti-pattern emerges as an error is arbitrary, and your case is an example.

The `class` atrribute of an element is for user-defined identifiers that distinguish between elements of the same semantic meaning for the purpose of behavior or presentation.  The unordered collection of class identifiers that pertain to an element is not bounded, in theory.  Thus, when you are designing your application and have to distinguish between elements, there is a simple, linear process for deciding whether a user-defined identifer is necessary and/or which attributes are involved:

1. **Is there an element or attribute other than *id* or *class* that semantically makes this distinction already?**  The HTML standard rigorously defines many tags and attributes, and by using them in a way that is consistent with the definitions, your application gains the benefits of all new related advances without duplication of work.  If new advances break your work, you will know when this will happen in advance by keeping up with the standard.
2. **Is there any possibility that the distinction will not be applicable in a given document or will be applicable to two or more elements?** The `id` attribute is defined as one per document; if it is useful in the static document, it could be referenced in a URI, but it must respect that one-to-one mapping or it just is not an `id`.  The shape of an element is thus appropriate if and only if the document relates some quality one-to-one with various shapes.
3. **If the above 2 clauses are ruled out, the distinction belongs to the `class` or `data` attribute.** If a distinction may have some representational correspondence that can be expressed in CSS, the `class` attribute is attractive.  If, however, the distinction is more quantifiable, continuous, or abstract, it may be better expressed as a `data` attribute.

In your case, the distinctions are *shape of element* and *user-clicked*.  Because *shape of element* is explicitly defined as not covered by HTML but deferred to CSS, a CSS construct is required to make that distinction.  This means there are few paths in your design: `style` attribute, `class` attribute, or entirely CSS implementation.  Since there is more logic involved than what CSS does and you are perhaps not wanting to define shapes in geometric terms, we can rule out `style` and pure CSS.  The `class` attribute is where both shapes of element should be distinguished.

Because the HTML standard does define the DOM concept of *user-clicked* and you have no further complications in time, your application should make use of the `onclick` event directly or through `jQuery` or your other favorite API.

Part of the evil magic of `$` is that learning it is much easier than learning the underlying parts, allowing you to succeed with incomplete understandings of the system up to a finite depth, then dumping you into the arms of stackoverflow.com when you first exceed that depth.  You must read the actual standards now.  Write up a working app without `$` at all and the mistake will be glaring so brightly that it will be seared into your eyeballs forever.  `$` is for people who have written enough DOM-based code to know that there just has to be a simpler easier way.  It should come as a relief when first used, not as a milder introduction to HTML app design.  Once you reach this epiphany, you are ready to get back to `$` and whatever else, but the DOM is not a black box or a class you can skip with footnotes.